# Adding a letter X using concat or substring in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, concatenation

So this is the part my query:

```
select concat('copy \\library\common\photos\',Image,'.',ImageType)
```

The result of the query will be this:

```
copy \\library\common\photos\{tuesday}_1pm\{tuesday}_1_ggc9070bsgdg763013a06a54b9bf54e5.png
```

I'm a little confused on how logic of this query works, it simply add the type of image extension to end of image from that same folder. Is there way I can a letter like A or B in from the image?

So result will be this from the query:

```
copy \\library\common\photos\{tuesday}_1pm\X{tuesday}_1_ggc9070bsgdg763013a06a54b9bf54e5.png
```

Anyway I can use substring to add that extra letter in front?

Comment: [Concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Can you please write an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Haha, my comment is not really sufficient as an actual "answer", an answer should be more than just a link to documentation :) But I figured that was probably all you needed.

Comment: insert it in the `concat()` before the `Image` :-  `select concat('copy \library\common\photos','X',Image,'.',ImageType)`

Comment: @Squirrel IT WILL GOES IN FRONT OF IMAGE THOUGH

Comment: You need to parse `Image` and split into the `path` and `filename` and the `concat()` with the inserttion of `X` in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the `Image` and split into the file path and file name. Then use `concat()` to concatenate into required string with `X` inserted in between

```
select  concat('copy \library\common\photos', ImagePath, 'X', ImageName, '.', ImageType)
from    yourtable
cross apply
(
    select  ImagePath = left(Image, p + 1),
            ImageName = right(Image, len(Image) - p - 1)
    from    (
                select  p = len(Image) - charindex('\', reverse(Image))
            ) p 
) p
```